# Convert Android/iOS into Website

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mean.io

We have built the iOS and Android app using mongodb and node.js. The mongodb/node.js have been completed.

Part of the functions is a "marketplace" service, which allows users to search for the merchants based on a set of criteria. The merchant must register their account using our app and all the edits will be carried out on the app only.

Now, we want to build a website that provides the marketplace service, i.e. PC users would go to our website, perform search and review the merchant's profile, which is similar to instagram (users upload/edit the image using the app, but the instagram web only allows user to browse the photo only.

I am not familiar with website development. I googled and the MEAN stack word always appear on the search result. But given i have completed the mongodb/node.js, i wonder if any back-end programming is needed or are any changes are needed on my own mongodb/node.js

Comment: Why is this tagged with Android? A description of the project isn't really required here, but it's hard to determine what your problem is other than not having a frontend web app for the backend node/mongo services

Comment: Yes, i want a frontend web app based on node.js/mongodb service. 
Android is tagged as i think some might have the same experience........

Comment: Your web app is entirely separate from the backend. Assuming you have a REST API, you could write the website in PHP, Java, Python, or Node web frontend. Angular is also optional. The MEAN stack simply combines the node backend and frontend